# "Vom Pferd erzählen", genaue Bedeutung und Herkunft der Redewendung

Tags: etymology, idiom

Eine ursprünglich als völlig intuitiv verstehbare und nicht weiter hinterfragte Redewendung erwies sich erst kürzlich als möglicherweise ungewöhnlicher als gedacht.

Sucht man im Netz nach "einen vom Pferd erzählen" wird man erschlagen von Plagiaten die den Ursprung fast immer auf das griechische Holzpferd vor Troja zurückführen wollen.

[Wenige Ausnahmen](http://www.ebbertz.de/aktuelles/vom-pferd-erzaehlen.html) bemühen eine Erklärung, die sich mit echten Pferden und ihren wohl meist adeligen Reitern an einer Erklärung versucht.

Auch wenn Pferd und indoeuropäische Sprache da eine sehr alte Verbindung vermuten lassen kann:
Die hier zweite Variante erscheint mir gerade als wahrscheinlicher.

Woher kommt diese Redewendung, was bedeutete sie ursprünglich, wie wird sie heute überwiegend gebraucht bzw. verstanden?

Comment: Die Herkunft vom Trojanischen Pferd halte ich auch für sehr unwahrscheinlich. Die Redewendung ist viel zu volkstümlich, als dass sie auf Homer zurückgehen könnte.

Comment: Von was für einer Redewendung sprichst du eigentlich? Mir ist keine solche Redewendung bekannt, und bevor ich [tofros Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/39027/1487) gelesen habe, war mir auch völlig unklar, was damit gemeint sein könnte. (Aber vermutlich würde sich das ohnehin aus dem Kontext ergeben.) Allzu verbreitet scheint mir diese Redewendung jedenfalls nicht zu sein.

Comment: @tofro kann irgendwie belegt werden, ob die Bekkantheit der Geschichte im Volksmund nicht mit dem Alter der Redewendung korreliert? Und was soll Volkstümlich in diesem Zusammenhang bedeuten? Immerhin ist die Redewendung abwertend gemeint, also kann kein Argument sein, das Volkstum sei der klassischen Lehre der antiken Geschichte abgeneigt. Gänzlich abgeneigt ist es aber wohl auch nicht.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zuerst: Die Redewendung scheint relativ neu zu sein - Das Grimmsche Wörterbuch von 1850 führt eine ganze Reihe von Redewendungen mit "Pferd" auf, die genannte ist *nicht* dabei. Die Volkstümlichkeit der Redewendung spricht auch nicht sehr für eine Herkunft von Homer.

Eine gute Erklärung findet sich meiner Meinung nach in der [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Redewendungen):

> **Jemandem einen vom Pferd erzählen** – jemanden täuschen. Als Pferde noch das Hauptverkehrsmittel waren, priesen die Pferdehändler oft die Leistungsfähigkeit ihrer Tiere, die sich nach dem Kauf jedoch nicht immer in der angekündigten Weise zeigte.

Der berüchtigte Hang zur Unwahrheit des Berufsstandes der Pferdehändler ("Roßtäuscher") scheint mir eine sehr gute Erklärung für die Redewendung zu sein.

Comment: Stimmt, wirklich sehr neu. Ich kenne sie erst, seit ich deine Antwort gelesen habe. Davor war mir diese Redewendung gänzlich unbekannt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ganz *so* neu ist sie jetzt auch wieder nicht...

Comment: Es scheinen einige Redewendungen auf Pferdehandel zurückzugehen, wie auch "Einem geschenkten Gaul schaut man nicht ins Maul", oder "Auf den Zahn fühlen" (Methoden, um das Alter des Pferds zu schätzen). Das macht m.E. auch in diesem Fall den Pferdehandel wahrscheinlicher als das Trojanische Pferd. Vielleicht muss man sich das so vorstellen, dass früher der Pferdehändler in etwa das war, was heute der Gebrauchtwagenhändler ist.

Comment: @tofro What's the English translation of the word "Volkstümlichkeit" that you use above in your answer? Is it "popularity"?

Comment: @EugeneStr. "volkstümlich" is located somewhere in the triangle between *popular*, *folkloric* and *simple-minded*, I'd say. The exact location inside that triangle depends quite a bit on context. My intention was more towards popular.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Vielleicht genießen Pferdehändler in Österreich einen besseren Ruf als in Deutschland :)

Comment: @LangLangC "Vom Pferd herunter" ist eine Erklärung, die gut zu "auf dem hohen Roß sitzen" paßt, also **Arroganz** impliziert. Zu einem Sachverhalt,  wo einem eine vollständige Unwahrheit erzählt wird, paßt sie meiner Meinung nach nicht bzw. ist für mich zu weit hergeholt. Zu Zeiten Adliger auf dem Pferd hatten die Untergebenen überhaupt kein Recht auf irgendeine Erklärung für irgendwas, nicht einmal auf eine offensichtliche Lüge.

Comment: *Rosstäuscher* klingt sehr stark nach einer Anlehnung an *Tauscher*, *Tauschhandel*, also einfach *Händler* (zumal die Worte tatsächlich verwandt sein sollen). Ich sehe zwar keinen Kommentar von LangLangC der sich auf "Vom Pferd herunter" (von oben herab) bezieht, finde das aber einen guten Einwurf. Vergleich bspw. *schwören*, En. *to swear* und *swearword*, oder Alt Deutsch "liugan" (heiraten, lügen; nicht ganz klar)--was mich übrigens an einer Ableitung wie etwa bei DWDS von *tauschen* aus einer ursprünglichen Bedeutung "die Wahrheit verdrehen" o.ä. zweifeln lässt.

Comment: Bzgl. Troja sei angemerkt, die Geschichte ist nicht unbedingt eine Tatsachenbehauptung, sondern könnte eine Metapher sein, bspw. über Männern auf braunen Pferden, die dem König in den Rücken fallen. Zwar unwahrscheinlich, da ein durchgehender Zusammenhang nicht belegt, wäre die Interpretation demnach *etwas Erzählen [wie in der Geschichte]*, nicht *von der Geschichte mit dem Holzpferd erzählen* (so laß ich das zuerst). Soll heißen, vielleicht spielt Homer auf die Redewendung bzw. die Idee dahinter an. Welch Ironie, falls die Männer als Söldner auch getauscht wurden, um Frieden zu garantieren.

Answer (score 2):

"Erzähl' mir doch nichts vom Pferd!" ist eine mindestens im süddeutschen Raum gängige Redewendung, mit der man zum Ausdruck bringt, dem Gegenüber zu unterstellen, daß dieser offensichtlich Unsinn erzählt (aus Unwissenheit oder auch um bewusst zu lügen / täuschen).

Beispiel: "Mein Hemd ist aus feinster Seide." - "Ach, erzähl mir doch nichts vom Pferd, das sieht doch jeder, daß das aus Polyester ist!"

Answer (score -1):

Zufällig stieß ich auf eine [Münchhausengeschichte](http://www.labbe.de/lesekorb/index.asp?themaid=95&titelid=814), die sehr gut auf die Redewendung passt. Da Münchhausengeschichten typischerweise grotesk sind passt die Erklärung, dass die Redewendung auf Münchhausen zurückgeht sehr gut, auf jeden Fall viel besser als auf das Trojanische Pferd, welches seine Täuschungsabsicht ja nicht verfehlte.

Kurz gefasst geht die Geschichte so: Der Baron lässt sein Pferd an der Tränke trinken und es säuft und säuft ohne Unterlass. Da dreht er sich um und sieht, dass die ganze hintere Hälfte fehlt, und das Wasser hinten wieder rausläuft. Beim Schließen des Stadttores sei die hintere Hälfte abgetrennt worden, da das Pferd erst halb durch war.

Heute ist Münchhausen nicht mehr sehr populär, aber vor 50 Jahren und mehr war das Volksgut.

Comment: Das hätte aber eher in der Redensart "Dein Pferd ist nicht ganz dicht" geendet...

Comment: Wieso hätte es das? Ich erzähl Dir ein Märchen, so unglaubwürdig wie das vom Pferd. Wieso würdest Du dann sagen "Dein Pferd ist nicht ganz dicht"?

Comment: das ist jetzt nicht sooo schwierig, oder?

Comment: Doch. Mir ist keine Theorie der Redensartgenese bekannt aus der sich Dein Schluss ergibt; er erscheint mir einfach nur geraten und zwar schlecht geraten. Mir fällt kein Beispiel ein, in dem eine Redensart so gebildet wurde - kennst Du eins?